# Are passwords in Edge saved in Microsoft Account?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

So I've setup my Windows 10 machine so that I login with my Microsoft account.

I was wondering, are passwords in Edge saved locally in the machine, or to my Microsoft Account?

The latter would be so convenient, like how Chrome passwords are saved in my Google account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

According to [this](https://www.faqforge.com/windows/windows-10/view-password-saved-microsoft-edge-browser-windows-10/). It's seems that it's saved on your computer.

> Microsoft Edge browser saves the passwords that you enter in web sites. You can view those saved passwords with the help of the Credential Manager. It is a free program which is available in latest Windows 10 (may be in previous versions, I didn't check). This article is written to help you view any saved password in Edge browser.

Comment: Credential Manager is built-into Windows.  You might want to mention that.